# What is the best monster to use as medic in final fantasy 13-2?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I often see the debate between the green and white chocobo being the best medic, which one is better?

Also, after stating which one is better, could you provide with how you are leveling & infusing it?

Comment: If you've seen the debate, you should have all the available info to make that decision for yourself.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Seeing a debate or someone stating one is better doesn't necessarily provide facts, especially if the said person doesn't provide a reason for their claim...

Comment: I'm still using Flanitor. I'm upgrading Cait Sith to max before figuring out which way to infuse them. Then I'll work on Chocobo's for medics and infuse into that. I'll probably go with White.

Answer (score 1):

i personly think green chocobo is the best medic.
i got him a few weeks ago and have stuck with him.
he has some great healing power but the only downside is it takes alittle Gil or farming to get the stuff for leveling him up. he starts to become a decent healer around level 40. and gosh who doesnt want a fluro green bird on there team =D